# Setting value of array updates variable used for index

Tags: c

When I update the value of an array in a C `struct`, sometimes but rarely the value of the `int` used as the index is also updated (`int` also from the `struct`). Is there something I am missing here about assignment?

```
struct Set {
   int data[STARTING_SET_SIZE];
   int count;
   int capacity;
};

#define STARTING_SET_SIZE 10

struct Set *constructSet()
{
    struct Set *set = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2 + STARTING_SET_SIZE * sizeof(int));
     set->count = 0;
     set->capacity = STARTING_SET_SIZE;
     return set;
 }

bool full(struct Set *set)
{
    return  set->count == STARTING_SET_SIZE;
}

void grow(struct Set *set)
{
   set = realloc(set, sizeof(int) * 2 + 2 * set->capacity * sizeof(int));
   set->capacity = set->capacity * 2;
}

void add(struct Set *set, int input)
{
   if (full(set)) grow(set)
   set->data[set->count] = input;
   set->count += 1;
}
```

For example if I add a bit more code to add to catch the error it throws occasionally i.e.

```
void add(struct Set *set, int input)
{
   int previousCount = set->count;
   set->data[set->count] = input;
   if (previousCount != set->count) {
       exit(1);
   }
   set->count += 1;
}
```

If I wrote this code in JAVA I would never see count changing in the first three lines of the add() function but I is something else in C going on here?

Below is the test script which initially showed me the error.

```
void testFullAndGrow()
{
   struct Set *set = constructSet();
   int i = 0;

   for (i = 0; i < STARTING_SET_SIZE * 2; i++) {
     add(set, i);
   }
}
```

Comment: Show the initialization part of the `struct`

Comment: Is this a multi threaded program? Is something else setting this value beside this function?

Comment: hi @AlterMann I have added the init function. Would you like to see the test function and main()?

Comment: What is glaring is you have not checked whether the array is already full, i.e. `if (set->count >= STARTING_SET_SIZE) exit(1)`. But the implication from the name `STARTING_SET_SIZE` and the presence of the field `capacity`, is that you expect to extend the array. You can only do that if the array memory was obtained from `malloc`. Here `set->data[]` is of fixed size.

Comment: I have added the memory full() and grow() functions. Excuse me for not adding them initially but from other languages perspective they seemed trivial and a waste of space but I can see with C they are more important.

Comment: "they seemed trivial and a waste of space" Help yourself and let the machine spot mistakes in your code. Leverage the machine. It's there. You paid for it. Don't let it procrastinate :)

Comment: agreed, I'm pleased I started learning C, I've learnt a lot so far :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You structure is not designed correctly. You want the fixed part to be first and the variable part to be last.

Since the array is variable, set its size to 0.

```
struct Set {
   int count;
   int capacity;
   int data[0];
};
```

This way, when you realloc the structure, count and capacity don't move.

Comment: Okay that makes sense now. Does that mean in C a 'struct' can only really have one variable sized array and that must be the last field?

Comment: What realloc will do is expand or copy and expand the memory (bytes) to another location. It has no idea of the internal structure. If you have more than one variable field, then it would be up to you to move the bytes around.

Comment: Thankyou @RobertJaobs , that solved it for me. Once I re-ordered the fields in the Set `struct` so that data was last my test started passing.

Answer (score 1):

Your `grow` function is badly written. You need to pass double pointer to it. If your newly reallocated memory starts on different address there's no way how to pass it back from the function.

Answer (score 0):

The function `full` will only work once.

```
bool full(struct Set *set)
{
    return  set->count == STARTING_SET_SIZE;
}
```

After you have grown the struct once, it will forever fail. I suggest

```
bool full(struct Set *set)
{
    return  set->count >= set->capacity;
}
```

I also suggest not doubling the capacity every time, that can get greedy on memory. I suggest adding a fixed amount, such as

```
set->capacity += STARTING_SET_SIZE;
```

Comment: Agreed, that would be the next step. I built it tdd and It failed on first time I added more than the capacity so I hadn't got around but yes that would be the way to go.

Comment: @RobertJacobs has the answer. OP forgot to mention it is going wrong  after growing the struct.